# Date format in PowerBI and different headers

Tags: powerbi, header, mapping, formula, date-formatting

can you advise on the following issue and propose a solution?
My original excel file has a column names Year/Month and the date format was 2021/06,2021/10 etc.When i upload the data to powerBI the date column has changed to dd/mm/yyy like 01/06/2021. Pls let me know how i can change it back to 2021/06 in BI?

Secondly, I have 2 files & each have 4 sheets (total 8 sheets). One of the file header is in Italian language & the other is in English. To combine both files data, i need to use the English headers. How to convert the Italian header to map to English?
English Headers: Total 24 columns; Other local language- Total 31 columns
I check which headers is suitable to be mapped to the English one.
Here are the list:

```
English               Local Language    Mapping to
Account               Account           Account (No change both file has the column)
Profit Center         Company           Profit Center
Document type         Type              Document type
Document Header Text  Batch             Document Header Text
Document Number       DocumentNo        Document Number
```

I have a long list of the headers. Please help and advise if possible to merger both headers?

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question in a single post. Edit your question, remove the second question, post a new question with the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you need in [Year/Month], you can modify your powerbi transformation; Search "changed Type" and edit {"Year/Month", type datetime} to {"Year/Month", type text} ;

OR

Select you [Year/Month] column from main pane -> Column Tool -> Format -> select what you need

[image]